# Return a variable after having been through several functions

Tags: python-3.x, function

So, I'm coding with Python 3.5.

For context, I am currently writing a program (relatively simple) that uses a menu to store in an instance of a class I defined the options that the user is going to use with that program. 
To write the menus, I have created several functions and I'm passing from one function to the other, always adding the instance containing the options as an argument.
I need to call the menu as a function, and have it return the instance after it goes through the menus.

My code and my problem can be simplified like that :

```
def spam(eggs):
    if eggs is None:
        bacon()
    return eggs

def bacon():
    eggs = ["spam, spam, spam, egg, and spam"]
    sausage(eggs)

def sausage(eggs):
    eggs.append("spam, spam, spam, spam, spam, spam, baked beans, spam, spam, spam, and spam")
    spam(eggs)

print(spam(None))
```

What I want is to be able to call `spam()` and have it return `eggs`.
In that case, which is basically the simplification of my code with what I believes matters in it when it comes to the issue I face, is that calling that function only returns `None`.

As I'm fairly new to Python, I do not understand why it doesn't work.

I know a possibility would be to make that class instance (represented here by the list `eggs`) a global variable, execute the function and get it back on another line, but I'd like to find a way to do it without using globals.

Comment: You need to add `return` to your functions everywhere, without return, they return `None` by default

Comment: @JeanRostan I'm always calling other functions before the return statement, though, so it only gets to return when I get to `spam`, only `if eggs is not None`, right ? I did try, and it doesn't change my problem, whether I add a blank return statement or I return `eggs`

Comment: See answer below, you need to return something from your functions to pass it to other functions.

Comment: @JeanRostan : Sorry, reading Xuewan Zhao's answer made me understand what you meant :) . Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
def spam(eggs):
    if eggs is None:
        return bacon()
    return eggs

def bacon():
    eggs = ["bacon"]
    return sausage(eggs)

def sausage(eggs):
    eggs.append("sausage")
    return spam(eggs)

print(spam(None))
```

You can change the strings as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

### Your Code

Let's look at what your code does.

```
def spam(eggs):
    if eggs is None:
        bacon()
    return eggs
```

Here is your first problem, `bacon()` neither prints anything, nor does it modify this version of `eggs`. Currently, it does not return anything either (it returns `None`). If it did, it wouldn't matter because you are not doing anything with the value it returns.

```
def bacon():
    eggs = ["spam, spam, spam, egg, and spam"]
    sausage(eggs)
```

Here it is unclear what you are trying to do. What is happening is that you are creating a `list` of one item -- which is the string `"spam, spam, spam, egg, and spam"`. If you wanted to create a list with each of those items in it as separate strings it would be `['spam','spam','spam','egg','spam']` or something similar depending on what you want to do with `'and'`.

The next issue is that you are storing it in `eggs`. However, this is not the same `eggs` as in `spam()` (it's a local variable) so any changes you make here will not be reflected in `spam()` unless you return whatever value you want to `spam()` where it can be assigned to that version of `eggs`.

The final issue with this function is the same issue that you had with `spam()` in that you are not doing anything with the value returned by `sausage(eggs)` and `sausage(eggs)` does not print anything -- So nothing is accomplished by running it.

```
def sausage(eggs):
    eggs.append("spam, spam, spam, spam, spam, spam, baked beans, spam, spam, spam, and spam")
    spam(eggs)
```

Similar problems in this function as in the previous two. Here, you are taking in the value of `eggs` that is found in `bacon()`. However, any modifications to it are ineffective as you do not modify that version and nothing is returned by `sausage()`.

`eggs.append(`...`)` has a similar issue as before in that you are simply adding one string to the end of the list, `eggs`, and not individual items. This may be your intention but the purpose is not clear.

`spam()` returns a value for `eggs` but nothing is done with the result. So nothing is accomplished with this statement.

```
print(spam(None))
```

### A Solution

This solution is an approximation of what you are trying to accomplish.

```
def spam(eggs):
    if eggs is None:
        return bacon()
    return eggs

def bacon():
    eggs = ["spam", "spam", "spam", "egg", "spam"]
    return sausage(eggs)

def sausage(eggs):
    eggs = eggs + ["spam", "spam", "spam", "spam", "spam", "spam", "baked beans", "spam", "spam", "spam", "spam"]
    return spam(eggs)

print(spam(None))
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and explanation !